# Change Map theme based on light in iOS app. How does Waze do it?

Tags: ios, swift

We show a map to the user and list stores around the user. We want to sense the available light and switch the theme automatically to a dark theme when it's dark. From SO search it seems there's IOKit that I could use but it also says, its not supported and Apple may not accept the app.

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/IOKit.framework

How does Waze or other apps do that?

Comment: What exactly does Waze do? The map changes color themes when you walk into a dark room or changes color themes at night?

Comment: I don't use it often but I think they do this using time, not light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always the tried and true method of using location services and looking up local sunset times... http://blog.instapaper.com/post/1538890633 (about halfway down, under "Dark Mode Improvements")

Comment: This is what I's thinking about but wanted to check if there's another way. Thank you!